# Does anyone know some good resources for Wicket Web Development?

Tags: java, wicket

I've recently "inherited" a web project from a workmate who left to join another company.  Unfortunately for us he was the only Java developer so I don't have anyone around the office here that can help me.

The project is written using the Wicket framework and this is not something I'm very familiar with (I've done a lot of ASP.NET and a little PHP).  I'm have a very difficult time getting my head around how things are working...

It seems the instantiation of the form includes the object the form is meant to manipulate but that's the only reference I see.  All the updates of values from the html form to the object seem to happen by magic!

Anyway... I digress...

I've tried to Google some stuff but it's all way above my head.  It's taken me a whole day just to get one more control onto a page without the page breaking when it loads.  It will probably take me all of tomorrow to get the page to submit without breaking.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial or something VERY entry-level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend Manning's [Wicket in Action](http://www.manning.com/dashorst/) - it provides a thorough overview of the framework complete with full working examples.  It will take you from 0 to "can make stuff using Wicket" as fast as you feel like going.

If you don't want to shell out the $27, here is a [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/wicket-tutorial-series-ui) to a Wicket tutorial.

And here's [another](http://www.javabeat.net/javabeat/wicket/tutorials/basics/3-an-interactive-hello-world.php).

Answer (score 2):

There are many useful examples at [the Apache Wicket site](http://wicket.apache.org/examples.html) and more at [Wicket-Library](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/)

Comment: Be careful with the Apache Wicket Site and Library regarding the version(s) of Wicket you are using. Some (and I am not saying most) of the examples over in the Apache Wiki are deprecated for newer versions and do not track to which version of wicket they correlate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this my post: http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2010/02/wicket-useful-links/

or try my Wicket tutorial: http://tomaszdziurko.pl/category/wicket-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [5 Days of Wicket](http://www.mysticcoders.com/blog/2009/03/09/5-days-of-wicket/)